# Ciclos dentro de funciones en JS

Tags: javascript

Me estoy iniciando en el mundo de la programación y he empezado con JS.
Estoy haciendo un ejercicio en el cual estoy un poco atascada y no estaría entendiendo cual es mi error.
Este es el enunciado:

"Escribí una función imprimirAzul, que toma como parámetro un valor numérico X e imprima "Azul" X cantidad de veces. IMPORTANTE te recordamos que "Azul" no es lo mismo que "azul" en este ejercicio debes utilizar "Azul" ".

```
Mi respuesta es esta:
function imprimirAzul(x){
    for (let i = 1 ; i<x; i++);{
        console.log("Azul"+i);
    }
}

imprimirAzul(4);
```

1. Definí la función imprimirAzul y le asigné un parámetro X.
2. Use la palabra reservada for y adentro toda su extructura.

El único error que me tira es que me dice que i no está definida; alguien me puede explicar cual fue mi error? la verdad es que me estoy rompiendo la cabeza y no logro hayar la solución!
Gracias a todos!

Comment: muchas gracias, ya lo corrijo!

Comment: De todos modos fijate que estás inicializando `let i=1` y luego la condicion es que `i<x` por lo que el resultado no va a ser el que esperas ya que va a empezar a contar de 1 en 1 hasta llegar a 3 (segun tu ejemplo en el que haces `imprimirAzul(4)`)

Comment: Hola Andrés, sí, tienes razón, ahí me ha complicado porque he llegado a otra instancia que no entiendo, justamente me tira este erro:

Comment: La ejecución de la función imprimirAzul(2) debe imprimir 2 veces 'Azul'
La ejecución de la función imprimirAzul(3) debe imprimir 3 veces 'Azul'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu código presenta varios problemas. No son muy graves por lo que, a medida que vayas aprendiendo vas corrigiendo estos errores.

El primero de estos errores viene en la instrucción `for (let i = 1 ; i<x; i++);{`. En JS los bloques de código tales como, **clases** o **métodos** se definen con `{}` por lo que, no es necesario el `;` en dicha instrucción.

Podríamos decir, que el `;` se reserva para "instrucciones simples", es decir, todas aquellas instrucciones que no supongan bloques de código.

Por otro lado, el código presenta un fallo en la instrucción `console.log("Azul"+i)`. Si mantienes dicha instrucción, genera el siguiente output:

```
Azul0
Azul1
Azul2
Azul3
```

Esto se debe a que estás **concatenando** la `string` "Azul" con la variable del loop `i`, por lo que, por cada iteración del bucle se concatena dicho resultado con la `string`.

Por tanto, sufragando dichos errores, el **código completo reproducible** sería:

```
function imprimirAzul(value) {
  for (i = 0 ; i<value; i++) {
    console.log("Azul");
  }
}
imprimirAzul(4)
```

El código genera el siguiente output:

```
Azul
Azul
Azul
Azul
```

Si deseas iniciar el loop en `i = 1`, de la forma:

```
function imprimirAzul(value){
  for (i = 1 ; i<value; i++) {
    console.log("Azul");
  }
}
imprimirAzul(4)
```

Este generará el siguiente output:

```
Azul
Azul
Azul
```

Por último, personalmente, te recomiendo que todas tus clases, métodos, funciones, variables, etc sean **autodescriptibles**, es decir, cuyo nombre sea fácilmente reconocible para el objetivo a cumplir. Esto compone un concepto que oirás mucho y son las "**Buenas Prácticas de Programación**".

Aplicando este concepto, he sustituido el parámetro `x` por el parámetro `value` para que el código sea un poco más **autodescriptible** y por ende, legible.

Comment: Justamente se me había generado ese problema a continuación y gracias a tu explicación he podido entender el error que se me generaba! te agradezco muchísimo!